# Nested event handlers not working

Tags: javascript

I have a marker that I am trying to add an infowindow to. First I display a pulldown for user to select a delete action. When user clicks delete, I display a delete confirmation prompt in the infowindow.  The yes/no button actions are getting called but I can't close the infowindow using _this.close().  In the debugger, it appears _this is pointing to the infowindow correctly but its not closing. Here is the code, overlayObj[pmid] is pointing to a google marker.

```js
this.overlayObj[pmId].listenerHandle[i++] =
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.overlayObj[pmId], 'rightclick',
    function(event) {

      var contentString = '<div><select id="overlayAction">' +
        '<option value="">Choose Action</option>' +
        '<option value="delete">Delete</option>' + // + pmId + '">Delete</option>' +
        '</select></div>';

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });

      infowindow.open(_this.overlayObj[pmId].get('map'), _this.overlayObj[pmId]);

      google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready',
        function() {

          var _this = this;
          // Reference to the DIV which receives the contents of the 
          // infowindow using jQuery
          var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
          //iwOuter.css({'background-color' : 'white'});

          // The div we want to change is above the .gm-style-iw div.
          // So, we use jQuery to get it using .prev().
          //
          var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

          // Remove the background shadow DIV
          iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({
            'display': 'none'
          });

          // Remove the white background DIV
          iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({
            'display': 'none'
          });

          var overlayAction =
            document.getElementById("overlayAction");

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(overlayAction, "click",
            function(event) {

              if (this.value == "delete") {

                // clear listeners on infowindow
                google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(_this);

                // set infowindow content to delete prompt
                var confirmString = '<div class="iw-container">' +
                  '<p>Delete item?</p>' +
                  '<button id="deleteIconButton">Yes</button>' +
                  '<button id="cancelDeleteIconButton">No</button></div>';
                _this.setContent(confirmString);

                google.maps.event.addListener(_this, 'domready',
                  function() {

                    var _this = this;
                    var deleteIcon =
                      document.getElementById("deleteIconButton");
                    var cancelDeleteIcon =
                      document.getElementById("cancelDeleteIconButton");

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(cancelDeleteIcon, "click",
                      function(event) {
                        _this.close();
                        google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(_this); // clears infowindow listeners
                      });

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(deleteIcon, "click",
                      function(event) {
                        _this.close(); // closes infowindow
                        google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(_this); // clears infowindow listeners
                        CpC.myMap.deleteIcon(pmId); // removes icon from map and db
                      });
                  });
              }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're adding a `domready` litener inside a `domready` handler for the same `infowindow`. But I think this event only fires once for a window.

Comment: Yes, I am. I set the infowindow content with new content after user selects delete, therefore, I need another domready listener.  Both of them fire and the last 2 domlisteners fire when user clicks either button.  _this.close is the only line that doesn't work for each button action.    I think I need to reorganize the code.  I just don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console when you call `_this.close`?

Comment: No error, but I figured it out.  Instead of setting the infowindow content to new html, I just close it and create a new infowindow.  I also restructured the code into 2 function calls, one function to create an infowindow with the delete dropdown and another function to create an infowindow with delete confirmation html.  Now I can reuse the functions for other widgets.